# Python import for testing within same package

Tags: python, unit-testing, pydev

My project hierarchy goes like this

```
project 
       src
          fruit_pkg
            count_fruits.py
       test
          fruit_pkg
             test_count_fruits.py
```

Now say inside the module `count_fruits.py` I have a function called `addition`. In order to test `addition`, do I have to import the `count_fruits` module using

```
my_mod = __import__("fruit_pkg.count_fruits")
cnt_fruit = getattr(my_mod,"count_fruits")
```

and then for my test do something like

```
def my_test(self):
  #some work happen here
  cnt_fruit.addition(blah, blah)
  #more work happen here
```

Or: since both the `src` and the `test` codes are in the same package `fruit_pkg`, is there a simpler way to access the functions inside `count_fruits`.

For parallel, in Java, if both the `src` and the junit test codes are inside the same package, no import is necessary at all.

Comment: Have you tried to do `from package.SRC.fruit_pkg.count_fruits import count_fruits`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `fruit_pkg` is a namespace package; it is available only from one directory. Look at `sys.modules['fruit_pkg']` to find out which one.

You could move tests to `src/fruit_pkg/test/test_count_fruits.py` or don't use the same top-level name for testing packages.

Either way, to import the module:

```
from fruit_pkg import count_fruits
```

Comment: After posting my question, I continued to play around with the import. Another suggestion led me to the correct answer before I saw your response. But I will accept your response as it turn out to be the final answer : `from fruit_pkg import count_fruits`. So thanks. But I have to up-vote the one by @Michael Wild for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

You do have to import the module (as that's how you get a reference to the module or any of its contents in the namespace of the other module), since the test code and product code are in different modules, but you don't have to do it in as complicated a way as you are.  You could just:

```
from fruit_pkg.count_fruits import count_fruits as cnt_fruit
```

Then again, it looks like you may have an over-complicated structure for your project.  Python generally favors flatter organizations than Java, so there's a good chance that it would make more sense to just put the `count_fruits` method directly in a `fruit_mod` module and not have  `fruit_pkg` at all.  That would make your project a bit easier to navigate, and also remove the redundancy in the import statement:

```
from fruit_mod import count_fruits
```

Comment: Thanks for helping lead me to the correct response, which turns out to be the one by @J.F. Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Splitting one package into multiple paths is not that simple in Python. [pkgutil.extend_path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.extend_path) will do the trick, but requires you to put this code into your `__init__.py` of the package:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Be aware that only the first `__init__.py` for that namespace in the `sys.path` (PYTHONPATH) is loaded. Thus you should make sure the `__init__.py` is the same for all parts that make up your package.

All in all this is error prone and I would recommend you to reorganize your code and just put the tests into their own separate namespace. Fiddeling with the `__path__` of a package can cause a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [py.test](http://pytest.org), you have to place an empty `__init__.py` in the `test` and `test/fruit_pkg` folders and then inside the `test_fruit_counts.py` import your module in whichever way you want, e.g

```
from src.fruit_pkg.count_fruits import *
```